Ctrl + NumberpadPlus doesn't work
I can't expand the selection range by pressing Ctrl + Numberpad + in Blender. I also can't shrink the selection range with Ctrl + Numberpad -.
However, I can use Numberpad + itself, and NumLock is not the issue.
What could be the cause?

But you are in Edit Mode? Or in Object Mode or any other? Is the mesh connected to the parts to which you want to extend the selection?

Does it work if you use the Select More/Less menu entry instead? The keymap entries are in Preferences > Keymap > Name: 'select more' or 'select less' under the Mesh entry.

It works correctly when I execute 'Select More/Less' from the menu. The issue occurs only when using 'Ctrl + NumpadPlus' in Edit Mode. It doesn't work in any mode, whether vertex, edge, or face selection.

I would follow @JohnEason 's tip to look in the keymap... maybe somehow something has changed...? By accident or some add-on?

I downloaded and installed Blender 3.6 from the official website. I haven't installed any add-ons or made any changes to the keymap. Just to be sure, I tried using a different keyboard, but the same issue occurs
